# Send local Push Notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am trying to send a push notification locally with swift, immediatelly (read: not scheduled for the future).

I am trying

```
          var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
        localNotification.alertBody = "Some text here"
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

with permission to send push notifications having been already granted.

Though the code is getting called, no push notification is sent. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your problem is, that you just don't see the answer.(Check my answer for more informations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to set the [timeZone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/timeZone) as localTimeZone

> The date specified in fireDate is interpreted according to the value
>   of this property. If you specify nil (the default), the fire date is
>   interpreted as an absolute GMT time, which is suitable for cases such
>   as countdown timers. If you assign a valid NSTimeZone object to this
>   property, the fire date is interpreted as a wall-clock time that is
>   automatically adjusted when there are changes in time zones; an
>   example suitable for this case is an an alarm clock.

// App delegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil))
        return true
    }
```

/// View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
        localNotification.alertBody = "Some text here"
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have make sure to **register notifications** for your app (for example in `AppDelegate`).
In Objective-C I have managed to do this using:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

#else

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

#endif
```

Then your code will get executed.

Another thing is, that you may simply not see them if you're using an app in foreground - try opening `Notification Center` by swiping down.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be that you don't see the notification, but it's actually there. Just open the notification-center and it should be there:

[image]

To check that, implement the `didReceiveLocalNotification` method into your AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
        println("Notification done")
    }
```

Then you can handle your notification and show a PopUp or whatever you want.